# How to dynamically load the material-ci-icons icon

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I use `Material-ui@next` and  `material-ui-next@next`

`material-ui@next` load one icon usage:

```
import AddIcon from 'material-ui-icons/AddIcon';
function AddIconButton(props) {
    return (
        <AddIcon />
    );
}
```

But I want dynamically load the material-ci-icons icon

For example, I have variable menus

```
const menus = [
  {
    Name: 'menu1',
    Icons: 'face',
  },
  {
    Name: 'menu2',
    Icon: 'extension',
  }
].
```

How to display the icon on the page according to the menus

Comment: You should elaborate on what you want to do and what you tried to achieve that, and ask a *specific* question about where you're stuck. It's much easier to answer a question when context and details are provided. You don't even mention which technology you're using here.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with this problem too. i use this link:
[dynamically load an icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369444/how-can-i-dynamically-load-an-icon-using-its-snake-case-name-react-material-ui).
save my menu icon name at database and use  `<Icon>{props.iconName}</Icon>` but, it doesn't work for me.
so because i don't have so much time i just save the SVG format of material ui icon in my database and restore it at my JSX.

i got SVG format of icons from inspect element of browser from material ui icon web page