# How can I dynamically load an icon using its snake_case name (React, material-ui)

Tags: reactjs, icons, material-design, material-ui

Normally I'd use material-ui icons by importing them directly [per the material-ui instructions](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/).

But I have a text tag, which is the actual icon name (like `calendar_view_day`) and need to get and render an icon component from it dynamically.

How can I something like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Icon name="calendar_view_day" color="primary" />
  )
}
```

Instead of:

```
render() {
  return (
    <CalendarViewDay color="primary" />  // Imported by name
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Folks it's almost 2024, use Font Material Icon. Super lightweight:

```
npm install material-icons@latest
```

Import in JS (example: `src/index.js` in Create React App `src/_app.js` in NextJS, `src/main.js` in Vue CLI):

```js
import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

In your component:

```js
import { Icon} from '@mui/material';

...

<Icon>{name}</Icon>
```

Just be aware icon name are small case and underscore separated

Comment: This creates a `<span />` and not a `<svg />`. This may not be a big deal in a lot of cases but sadly a deal breaker for my use case.

Comment: How are you able to retrieve a list of icon names that match a specific query? This is what I cannot find documentation on.

Answer (score 21):

### Later Edits

EDIT 2: Look at @Roozbeh's more up-to-date mid-2023 answer on using Font Material Icon before using the following.

---

EDIT 1: This answer is for MUI v4, MUI v5 answers below (but untested by me)

### Correct answer

Turns out `material-ui` includes an icon component that allows you to do this... and it converts names itself, so accepts snake, pascal and other variants. *BEWARE this will massively increase bundle size, as pointed out in the comments. If you're bundle size constrained, you'll have to take a different approach of serving the icon SVGs from somewhere!*

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon'

...

render() {
  return (
    <Icon>{props.iconName}</Icon>
  )
}
```

### Previous answer (working but massive overkill)

Create function to:

- convert snake_case to PascalCase
- Handle special cases reported in [the material-ui icons documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#svg-material-icons)

...Then use the material-ui Icon component.

Here's the code:

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon'

function upperFirst(string) {
  return string.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1, string.length)
}

function fixIconNames(string) {
  const name = string.split('_').map(upperFirst).join('')
  if (name === '3dRotation') {
    return 'ThreeDRotation'
  } else if (name === '4k') {
    return 'FourK'
  } else if (name === '360') {
    return 'ThreeSixty'
  }
  return name
}

...

render() {
  const iconName = fixIconNames(props.iconName)
  return (
    <Icon>{props.iconName}</Icon>
  )
}
```

Comment: importing the whole _Icon_ module from _material-ui_ will resolve the functionality, but will **explode** the bundle! You can analyze the bundle size via [React official guideline](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/analyzing-the-bundle-size)

Comment: Thanks @Navid, added a health warnign to my answer.

Comment: This solution uses font icons instead of svg icons. Requires the used font to be loaded. See: https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#icon-font-icons

Comment: The 'correct answer' only prints the string props.iconName for me, doesn't show the actual icon.

Comment: @jonasRosenvist, you also need to include some link into your code:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />

Comment: this solution worked for me - <Icon>save</Icon>; The icon name should be lower case without the "Icon" suffix. Something like ChevronRight - should be changed to chevron_right.  You have import the material_icon CSS file in index.js

Answer (score 5):

MUI 5 developers here you go.

```
import * as Muicon from "@mui/icons-material";
const Icon = Muicon['SatelliteAlt']
<Icon fontSize="large" sx={{ px: 1 }}/>
```

Typescript

```
import * as MUIcon from "@mui/icons-material";
interface IconProps {
   icon?: keyof typeof MUIcon;
}
const IconComp: React.FC<IconProps> = ({
  icon,
}) => {
    const Icon = icon && MUIcon[icon];
    return ({Icon && <Icon />})
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sufiyan, edited my answer to point to this for v5.

Comment: The `return` line in `IconComp` results in a parsing (unexpected token) error when compiling (and it's not clear to me what this is doing or how it is intended to be used).

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, {createElement } from "react";
import * as MuiIcons from "@material-ui/icons";

export default ({ iconName }) => (
  <div>
      {createElement(MuiIcons[iconName])}
  </div>
);


<ComponentWithIcon iconName="Add" />
<ComponentWithIcon iconName="Anchor" />
```

Comment: Your approach is simple but inefficient because it includes all icons in the bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a component that allow you to **create a component from string** like this :

```
<MIcon name={'AccessAlarms'} sx={{ mr: 0.5 }}/>
```

Component in typescript :

```
import { IconTypeMap } from '@mui/material'
import * as MUIcon from '@mui/icons-material'

type IconProps = IconTypeMap['props']

interface MIconProps extends IconProps {
  name: string | undefined
}

export default function MIcon(props: MIconProps) {
  const { name } = props
  const Icon = MUIcon[name as keyof typeof MUIcon]
  if (Icon == null) {
    throw `There is no "${name}" Icon`
  }
  return <Icon {...props} />
}
```

You can pick the name of the icon from https://mui.com/material-ui/material-icons/

Other generic Icon props are also available in this component such as `sx`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments to *thclark*'s answer above, the solution using the Icon component will use the font version of the Material-UI icons, which doesn't contain the full icon-set.

By using the same method to get the correct icon name (borrowed from *thclark*) combined with React.createElement does the trick. I did this in TypeScript, it's even easier in vanilla javascript. Here comes the component in TS version (dynamicIcon.tsx), also available in [this repo](https://github.com/frazer84/react-dynamic-material-icon-ts):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Icons from '@material-ui/icons/';

type IconType = typeof import('@material-ui/icons/index');

interface DynamicIconProps {
    iconName: string,
    className: string
}

function upperFirst(string:string) {
    return string.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1, string.length)
}
  
function fixIconNames(string:string) {
    const name = string.split('-').map(upperFirst).join('')
    if (name === '3dRotation') {
        return 'ThreeDRotation'
    } else if (name === '4k') {
        return 'FourK'
    } else if (name === '360') {
        return 'ThreeSixty'
    }
    return name;
}

export default class DynamicIcon extends React.Component<DynamicIconProps> {
    constructor(props: DynamicIconProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return React.createElement(Icons[fixIconNames(this.props.iconName)! as keyof IconType], {className: this.props.className});
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done for providing a TS solution. But the creation of the element was never the problem - it's the bundle size. I don't use TS but as far as I can see, in order to work, this must still import every single icon into the bundle (check https://create-react-app.dev/docs/analyzing-the-bundle-size/).

Answer (score 0):

Importing whole Icons from @mui increasing my build size by 4MBs which is something I wasn't looking for, so finally I solved it like this

```
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import * as React from "react";



import { Props } from "./types";


function cameltoSnakeCase(text = "") {
    return text
        .replace(/([A-Z])/g, "_$1")
        .toLowerCase()
        .slice(1);
}


const IconPresentation = ({ glyph, sx }: Props) => {
    if (!glyph) return null;
    return <Icon style={{ ...sx }}>{cameltoSnakeCase(glyph?.toString())}</Icon>;
};


export default IconPresentation;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way

```
import { SvgIconComponent } from '@mui/icons-material';

const MUIcon: { [key: string]: SvgIconComponent } = require('@mui/icons-material');

const CompA = () => {
  const renderIcon = (iconName: string) => {
    const Icon = MUIcon[iconName];

    return (
       {Icon && <Icon />}
    )
  }
}
```