# Invalid prop `children` of type `string` supplied to `ForwardRef(ListItemIcon)` when using .map to create MUI list items

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So i am trying to create a dynamic navigation sidebar for my react app with Material UI. I saved all of the information i should need in a DB. Then i pull the information out of the db and use .map to create the sidebar links. I have everything working besides the " part, those dont render. When mapping the data to my  'template' the following error pops up:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `string` supplied to `ForwardRef(ListItemIcon)`, expected a single ReactElement.
```

my source array:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:{id: 0, label: "Dashboard", link: "/dashboard", icon: "<HomeIcon />"}
1: {id: 1, label: "test", link: "/test", icon: "<SettingsInputComponentIcon />"}
2: {id: 2, label: "test1", link: "/test1", icon: "<TypographyIcon />"}
3: {id: 3, label: "test2", link: "/test2", icon: "<NotificationsIcon />"}
```

I believe the issue is because the "icon" field is in double quotes. I have been trying to get the icon value out of quotes with with following methods:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i] = data[i].icon.replace(/"/g, "");
```

or just placing it when i'm mapping like this:

```
    <ListItemIcon>
      {icon.replace(/"/g, "")}
    </ListItemIcon>
```

Is there an approved way to do this?

EDIT:

I wanted to point out that i am importing the icons from material UI as follows:

```
import {
  Home as HomeIcon,
  NotificationsNone as NotificationsIcon,
  FormatSize as TypographyIcon,
  ArrowBack as ArrowBackIcon,
  SettingsInputComponent as SettingsInputComponentIcon
} from "@material-ui/icons";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### JSX !== HTML

JSX is a superset of JavaScript, meaning that you can't treat JSX as a string like you can with raw HTML.

If you're using Material UI's icons, you need to import their implementation like any other component and use the reference in your data.

```
import { AccessAlarm, ThreeDRotation } from '@material-ui/icons';

export const nav = [
  { id: 1, label: "test", link: "/test", NavIcon: AccessAlarm },
  { id: 2, label: "test2", link: "/test2", NavIcon: ThreeDRotation }
];
```

### ListItemIcon and React Element

[`ListItemIcon`](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item-icon/) `children` prop expects a single [React Element](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html).

> The content of the component, normally `Icon`, `SvgIcon`, or a `@material-ui/icons` SVG icon element.

An element is a rendered React component, e.g. the plain object returned by `React.createElement`. Though we don't want to pre-render these outside the render cycle of React since it'll mess up the lifecycle of the Icon components.

To achieve this, only keep the component type instead of a string.

```
{
  id: 3,
  label: "test2",
  link: "/test2",
  NavIcon: NotificationsIcon // also notice the capital "NavIcon" key.
}
```

Then, render the icon using its type. Something like the following

```
{data.map(({ id, label, link, NavIcon }) => (
  <ListItem key={id}>
    <ListItemText primary={label} />
    <ListItemIcon>
      <NavIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
  </ListItem>
))}
```

### [Dynamically loading icons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56369445/1218980)

If you really can't change the database format, it's possible to sanitize the icon names and load them by name later using the [Material UI `Icon` component](https://material-ui.com/api/icon/).

> children: The name of the icon font ligature.

If you can keep only the `"NotificationsIcon"` part of the string and remove any tag like special characters from the icons value in the database, then it would be only:

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';

// somewhere
const data = [
  { id: 1, label: "test", link: "/test", icon: "AccessAlarm" },
  { id: 2, label: "test2", link: "/test2", icon: "ThreeDRotation" }
]

// then when rendering
{data.map(({ id, label, link, icon }) => (
  <ListItem key={id}>
    <ListItemText primary={label} />
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Icon>{icon}</Icon>
    </ListItemIcon>
  </ListItem>
))}
```

But you most keep the name that Material UI is using to identify its icons.

---

Note that a string doesn't contain its own quotes as part of its value, so `.replace(/"/g, "")` does nothing at all and will return the same string, unless it had other `"` inside, like quoted string props.

```js
console.log("<SettingsInputComponentIcon />".replace(/"/g, ""))
// => "<SettingsInputComponentIcon />"
```

Comment: So when I pull from a DB all of the "values" are in quotes besides  my Bits. So if I change the column name to capital I, it will not put it in quotes?

Comment: @mister.cake No, you should not store JSX as a string inside any database.

Comment: I editing my question to show you how i am importing my Icons from material UI. Also i did what you said and changed the values in the DB to just the component type but am now getting the following error: <HomeIcon /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.

Comment: @mister.cake I updated my answer with a way to dynamically load the icons from material ui.

Comment: The icons i am importing are SVG icons i guess. As for the <Icon> tags "The Icon component will display an icon from any icon font that supports ligatures. As a prerequisite, you must include one, such as the Material icon font in your project, for instance, via Google Web Fonts". I can live with using those icons. thanks for your help.