# How to load dynamically mui icons from mui using typescript

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I want to load mui icons base on string  parameter by these snipped:

```
import Icon from "@mui/icons-material"
import SvgIcon from '@mui/material/SvgIcon';


const IconComponent = (props: typeof SvgIcon & {
    muiName: string;
}) => {
    return Icon[props.muiName]
}

export default IconComponent;
```

But bellow error ocuured:
[image]

How Can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, I ended up fixing it like this:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import * as Icons from '@mui/icons-material'

export type IconNames = keyof typeof Icons
export type IconProps = {
  iconName: IconNames
}

export const IconComponent: FC<IconProps> = ({
  iconName,
}) => {
  const Icon = Icons[iconName]
  return <Icon />
}
```

Comment: While calling the IconComponent, you have to do like this.
<IconComponent name = {item.icon as IconNames} />

Answer (score 0):

Have you really investigated ?
However:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56369445/12637199

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon'

...

render() {
  return (
    <Icon>{props.iconName}</Icon>
  )
}
```

Comment: Error occured after declare: Cannot find module '@material-ui/core/Icon' or its corresponding type declarations.

Comment: maybe it is an import problem ? are you using yarn or npm?

Comment: It seems .Im using npm

Comment: can you run `npm install @material-ui/core@next` please

Comment: It throw an error:ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Comment: can you remove your package.lock and add your package.json to your question please

Comment: unfortunately I cant . For an important reason

Comment: package.lock might cause your issue...